# AsyncTask code added to service in Android

Tags: android, android-service, siemens

I am very beginner in Android, I am creating android application, communication with Siemens PLC its working fine but if i click button only the data shown in android , I want to run this code in service I don't know how to add code(below) in service

```
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try{

                client.SetConnectionType(S7.S7_BASIC);
                int res = client.ConnectTo("10.0.2.2",0,1);
                if(res == 0)
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[4];
                    res = client.ReadArea(S7.S7AreaDB,1,0,2,data);
                    ret = "Values  "+S7.GetWordAt(data,0);
                }
                else {
                    ret = "Err:"+S7Client.ErrorText(res);
                }
                client.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ret= "Exe"+e.toString();
                Thread.interrupted();
            }
            return "Executed";
        }
```

Above code is working fine but this code added to service I create one service

```
public class MyService extends Service {
S7Client client = new S7Client();
String ret = "";
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    PlcReader task=new PlcReader();
    task.execute("");
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


public class PlcReader extends android.os.AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try{

            client.SetConnectionType(S7.S7_BASIC);
            int res = client.ConnectTo("10.0.2.2",0,1);
            if(res == 0)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[4];
                client.ReadArea(S7.S7AreaDB,1,0,4,data);
                ret = "Values  "+S7.GetWordAt(data,0);
            }
            else {
                ret = "Err:"+S7Client.ErrorText(res);
            }
            client.Disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ret= "Exe"+e.toString();
            Thread.interrupted();
        }
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ret,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I added code with service but shows connection problem

Comment: Create Async Task in service and call it from onStartCommand from service

Comment: can you give me any example code

Comment: check the example

Comment: I added code with service but it shows me connection problem

Comment: Is ip address not connect in service???

Answer (score 0):

See this example:-

```
public class ExtractService extends Service {


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

                AsyncTask task=new AsyncTask();
                task.execute();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


public class AsyncTask extends android.os.AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your `AsyncTask` from the method `onStartCommand` in the `Service`:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        new MyAsyncTask().execute("stringParameter")

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

A couple of tips:

I see that you return a String value from your `AsyncTask`, just avoid using

`String result = new MyAsyncTask().execute("stringParameter").get()`

As it will block your main thread (unless you start your async task in a different thread).
A more appropriate solution is to handle the result in the `onPostExecute` method in your `AsyncTask` (just override it)

Another thing to think about is that `AsyncTask` is deprecated in Android R, some good alternatives are the `java.util.concurrent` package and `RxJava` library